# jquery click event not working for dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery - Click event doesn’t work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

I just have a clickable add button that adds new table rows. The table rows include a delete button. I've noticed that when I dynamically add a new row the button does not fire the click event, but if the button exists when the page loads, then it works fine. How can I correct this?

Javascript:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {

        var newTr = '<tr><td><input id="column_0" name="column[0]" style="width:40%;" type="text" /> <img alt="Delete-icon24x24" class="btnDel clickable" id="" src="/assets/delete-icon24x24.png" /></td></tr>';
        $('#columns').append(newTr);
    });

$('.btnDel').click(function () {
    alert('hey');
    console.log('test');
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    alert(row);

    row.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll need to use event-delegation:

```
$("table").on("click", ".btnDel", function () {
    /* Respond to click here */
});
```

The reason is that you cannot bind a handler to items that don't presently exist in the DOM. You can, however, bind a handler to a delegate target (a parent element that will remain in the DOM). Clicks will bubble up the DOM, eventually reaching the delegate target.

We listen for clicks on the `table` and we evaluate whether they came from an `.btnDel` element. This will now respond to clicks from `.btnDel` elements loaded when the page loaded, as well as those that are added dynamically later.

Lastly, don't re-use ID values.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for the insight into why that does not work instead of just giving me a working example. Understood on the id, it was not my intention to leave there.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for event delegation for dynamically added html elements. You can delegate event to `parent` element of dynamically added elements if you can or you can delegate to `document`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnDel', function () {
    alert('hey');
    console.log('test');
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    alert(row);

    row.remove();
});
```

**[Delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

For further understanding read this article [Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 3):

use `on()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnDel', function(){
  //your code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {

       var newTr = '<tr><td><input id="column_0" 
       name="column[0]"style="width:40%;"type="text" />
      <img alt="Delete-icon24x24" class="btnDel clickable" id="" 
       src="/assets/delete- icon24x24.png" /></td></tr>';
    $('#columns').append(newTr);

       $('.btnDel').click(function () {
       alert('hey');
       console.log('test');
       var row = $(this).closest("tr");
       alert(row);

       row.remove();
     });



      });
```